# How to hide an element completely after a transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a label and a small input box inline with one another. Below this row, I have some static text.

When the input box is hovered over, the input box will grow towards the left side and "hide" the inline text beside it.

What I notice is that after the input box finishes transition to it's full width, an empty line gets created below (the invisible inline text gets pushed to the next row).

I've tried using the display: none attribute, but unfortunately, transitions and display don't play nice together.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <input />
  <label>Hide Me</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Static Text</label>
</div>
```

CSS(LESS):

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;

  label {
    transition: all ease 1s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
  }

  input {
    float: right;
    transition: width 2s ease;
    width: 0;

    &:hover {
      width: 200px;
    }
  }

  input:hover + label {
    visible: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all ease 0s;
    transition-delay: 0;
  }
}
```

Here's a demo: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mattliang/pen/MXdLNq?editors=1100)

Is there a way to hide the inline text completely (basically as if the inline text had display:none applied) without Javascript?

I have an idea of how to solve this with javascript by checking when the transition is completed. But I'm curious to know if there's a CSS-only solution.

Comment: You know that 300px won't fit in a 200px container...right?

Comment: Ah yes, I'll edit that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you need?

```css
fieldset{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  border:none;
  background:#26a69a;
}
label{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color:white;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  transition:opacity 385ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
input{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  width:5px;
  right:5px;
  top:8px;
  transition:all 385ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

fieldset:hover label{
  opacity:0;
}

fieldset:hover input{
  width:195px;
  right:10px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <label>Hover on me</label>
  <input type="text"/>
</fieldset>
```

hope this helps

Comment: Interesting approach. I'm selecting this as the solution because the input is able to span across the entire width of the container. I made some tweaks to fit my case, but this really helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it `width:0` and use `white-space:nowrap`.

*I used `max-width` to be able to rely on transition*

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  font-size:0;
}
.container label {
  font-size:initial;
  transition: all ease 1s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  max-width:200px;
}
.container input {
  float: right;
  font-size:initial;
  transition: max-width 2s ease;
  max-width: 0;
  width:100%;
}
.container input:hover {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.container input:hover + label {
  max-width:0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input><label>Hide Me</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Static Text</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even when the label is set to max-width: 0, the label still seems to be there, not allowing the input to fully cover the space where the inline text existed. Do you know if there's any way to get the input to span across the entire width?

Comment: @GloriousLemon check the update ;) simply need to use 100% in the width ... I have changed it

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You could add a fixed height, and use `overflow: hidden`. It's not necessarily the best way, but does function: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGaazq?editors=1100

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes